# Keep getting beaten All In with AA

Tags: all-in, pot-odds

I keep getting beaten with my strong hands like AA by weaker hands...what am I doing wrong?

I really want to get good at poker, I understand what hands to fold and which to play, but somehow I'm just drawn into these situations and lose, kicking myself afterwards.

This is a quick log of how my loss went down:

I have 500 in the pot, same as my opponent, this is a spin and go game

I'm holding AA and raise preflop, it gets called.

Flop comes KJ (both spades) and an 8 of some kind

I check, but my thought process is that I'll try and gain value on the river as I beat both of those pairs.

Turn comes deuce, and my opponent goes all in.

I call him and go All In, thinking my Aces would be good

He reveals 22 and wins pot.

Is that just unlucky or is there any way I can identify when someone is holding better than an AA?

Comment: If you are playing low stakes. You generally shouldn't play tricky. You have a good hand on the flop with the pre-flop aggression, go ahead and bet. Your call isn't bad, just unlucky. But always ask yourself if you played your hand optimal. I don't have enough information to give my thoughts. First play and master ABC poker before mixing in tricky strategies.

Answer (score 2):

Did you hold the ace of spades?  What bet sizing?

You have AA and your thought is to wait for the river to value bet?

Not a spot to slow play with a flush draw and two paint on the board. He could have a pair and improve to 2 pair or trips.

Slow play only when you have a monster like a set of kings.  Here you should not slow play because of the flush draw.

If they held K or J they would call 1/2 pot bet on the flop. You need to drive out a flush draw. You need to bet 1/2 to a full pot here.

On the turn a deuce is a blank.  If you get beat by a set that is poker but you let them see a free turn.

22 does make sense there. A single pair would not likely jam. If you did not think this person was capable of a bluff then you would need to fold.

Comment: Thanks mate. My thought process was that since I thought my hands was strong I didn't want to bet on the flop and have him fold because I enter him to stick around and bet.

Comment: I think @Paparazzi makes the key point about this question, waiting for the river to value bet. There is not need to play tricky against weak players. In fact playing tricky gets you into bad situations. Weak players are not thinking in depth about the game, so often you can keep it simple and value bet every street. If they fold, it doesn't matter you win a pot.